# Use current calendar date in SQL

Tags: oracle-apex

If I navigate through the calendar using the next button I want to use the first date as a parameter in the calendar SQL statement. Is this possible?

[image][image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(".fc-day").first().attr('data-date')
```